# Using custom exception and defining it in final constants

Tags: java

I have define the custom exception class and later i am using it in my other class where i am throwing that exception as shown below

My custom exception :-

```
public class AaestroCardNetworkException  extends Exception {
    public AaestroCardNetworkException(String message) {
            super(message);
    }
}
```

and in later part i am using it as shown below

```
        TTTM_DB_LIST = astmDAO.getRTTMDBList(Code, "AE");
if (RTTM_DB_LIST.isEmpty()) {
    throw new masterCardNetworkException(" Job code is null in database");
}
```

Now as shown above i am having this check multiple times in my class, so what i am planning to  keep a separate final class where i can keep this constant and later on i can use the same constant in my above class, please define which approach should i choose also please define can i also use Enum here also

Comment: If `RTTM_DB_LIST` is a constant, why do you need to check it multiple times at runtime? Or can you perhaps explain how/when you need to perform this check?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the connection between the exception and defining a final constant? What is the final constant you plan to use and how? Please [edit] your question and make it clearer.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele RTTM_DB_LIST is an array list which is getting from Database

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am planning to store the custom message in an constants final class

Comment: @sdsddsds You can already do that with ResourceBundles.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do. Please [edit] your question, add some code. You can mention that this is not working code but what you "want" to do - as long as we understand what is doing what. Use a lot of comments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a constant and thinking in terms of data field, try to take a more object-oriented approach and think in terms of behaviour.

You need some kind of objects that gives you a list of something, and there are some case when it's state is incorrect so you must throw an exception to represent this situation.

Here it is (I invented some of the other types it relies on for the sake of example):

```
public interface Rttms {
  List<Rttm> rttms() throws AaestroCardNetworkException;
}
```

Now you need an implementation for this, I don't know how you retrieve the content of this list exactly, but this is where it happens:

```
public class DbRttms implements Rttms {
   private final Database db;
   public DbRttms(Database db) {
       this.db = db;
   }

   public List<Rttm> rttms() throws AaestroCardNetworkException {
      if (/* can't retrieve list from db */) {
          throw new masterCardNetworkException(" Job code is null in database");
      } else {
          return /* the list */
      }
   }
}
```

Once you have this, you can have a static constant holding this object somewhere in your code, or you can pass it around, it is as you want (I would recommend avoiding static but that's another story).

If you don't want to retrieve it everytime but only the first time, you can write an implementation of this class that caches its value:

```
public class CachedRttms implements Rttms {
  private final Rttms origin;
  private List<Rttm> cached;
  public CachedRttms(Rttms origin) {
    this.origin = origin;
  }

  public List<Rttm> rttms() throws AaestroCardNetworkException {
    if (this.cached == null) {
      this.cached = this.origin.rttms();
    }
    return this.cached;
}
```

And so on.